# Can decltype declare an r-value?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, decltype

```
// Compiled by Visual Studio 2012

struct A
{
    bool operator ==(const A& other) const
    {
        for (decltype(this->n) i = 0; i < n; ++i) // OK
        {}

        return true;
    }

protected:
    size_t n;
};

struct B : public A
{
    bool operator ==(const B& other) const
    {
        for (decltype(this->n) i = 0; i < n; ++i) // error C2105: '++' needs l-value
        {}

        return true;
    }
};
```

**Is this a bug of VC++ 2012?**

Comment: Types aren't r-values or l-vales; types are *types*. The l-value/r-value classification is for *expressions*.

Comment: For reference, it compiles under gcc 4.6.3 with the C++0x flag. I think this is right, considering both your loops are identical.

Comment: The type for i in B::operator== is deduced as const int, looks like a VC bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a VS2012 compiler bug. The spec is quite clear on this, in section 7.1.6.2, paragraph 4. Indeed, one of the examples given shows an expression that references through a const-pointer `a`. `decltype(a->x)` yields `double`, while `decltype((a->x))` yields `double const &`.

So it's a bug; the compiler thinks that `i` is `const`, and therefore can't `++` it.